# SQL Error (update gegevens):: Unknown column '1' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I Know this is a 'well-known' problem, but I can't get it working. The following MySQL Query (in PHP) gives me this error

```
 $sqle = "UPDATE $gameID SET `$column` = `$vav` WHERE drank='$drank'";
 $resulte = mysql_query($sqle) or die('SQL Error (update gegevens):: '.mysql_error());
```

I tried a lot of different quotes, but I can't get it working. Can someone send me in the right direction?

also;

```
$column = 'prijs_max';
$vav = $INFO[$count+1];  // returning a number
```

---

The complete loop after editing

```
$count = 0;
    foreach ($INFO as $value) {
        $column = "";
        if(strpos($value, '§') !== false) {
            $pieces = explode('§', $value);
            $drank = $pieces[0];
            $rang = $pieces[1];

            if ($rang == 'start') {
                $column = 'prijs_start';
            } elseif ($rang == 'min') {
                $column = 'prijs_min';
            } elseif ($rang == 'max') {
                $column = 'prijs_max';
            }

            if ($column == 'prijs_start') {
                $bidmaxquery = "SELECT drank FROM $gameID WHERE drank = '$drank'";
                $bidmax = mysql_query($bidmaxquery) or die('SQL Error (get drank) :: '.mysql_error());

                if (mysql_num_rows($bidmax) == 0) {
                    $vav = $INFO[$count+1];
                    $inc = $INFO[$count+7];
                    $sqld = "INSERT INTO $gameID (drank,$column,prijs_current,increment) VALUES ('$drank','$vav','$vav','$inc')";
                    $queryd = mysql_query($sqld) or die('SQL Error (insert eerste gegevens):: '.mysql_error());
                }
            } else {
                $vav = $INFO[$count+1];
                echo $vav;
                echo "<br>";
                $sqle = "UPDATE $gameID SET `".$column."`=$vav WHERE drank='$drank'";
                $resulte = mysql_query($sqle) or die('SQL Error (update gegevens):: '.mysql_error());
            }

        }
        $count ++;
    }
```

Comment: What's the data type of your prijs_max column?

Comment: All of my columns are VARCHAR(25).

Comment: Hmm, the values DO get imported in the database tho.

Comment: I Left out 'or die('SQL Error (update gegevens):: '.mysql_error());' .. working fine now :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
"UPDATE $gameID SET `".$column."`='$vav' WHERE drank='$drank'";
```

Comment: This got me a little further, but still I'm getting an error. I'm looping something and it's giving me the same error in the last loop. I will look further into this.

Comment: Yes, the column name is correct. It's giving me this error when my $vav is a floating number, like 0.3

Comment: Still, SQL Error (update gegevens):: Unknown column '' in 'field list'. I Will post the complete loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE $gameID SET $column ='$vav' WHERE drank='$drank'";
```